# Why does this UIButton flicker upon hiding?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, swift

I created a UIButton in my controller (as part of Stanford's Matchismo app lesson) that hides when the deck of cards is empty. Another button then unhides, prompting the user to shuffle the deck.

The problem is that I see a flicker of the "back card" (which is the default state background image) before the button hides. I don't understand why this occurs since I've removed any highlight changes to the button image.

Here is the XML of the view:

```
<button tag="1" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" adjustsImageWhenHighlighted="NO" adjustsImageWhenDisabled="NO" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ypz-af-BtM">
                                <rect key="frame" x="115" y="224" width="90" height="119"/>
                                <color key="tintColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                <state key="normal" backgroundImage="Card Back"/>
                                <state key="disabled" backgroundImage="Card Front"/>
                                <state key="selected" backgroundImage="Card Front"/>
                                <state key="highlighted" backgroundImage="Card Front"/>
                                <connections>
                                    <action selector="touchCardButton:" destination="GP9-BH-jNX" eventType="touchUpInside" id="Htd-Uc-LJN"/>
                                </connections>
                            </button>
```

And here is the controller method:

```
 @IBAction func touchCardButton(sender: UIButton) {
        self.flipCount++
        if sender.selected{
            if self.cardDeck.cards.count <= 0{
                sender.hidden = true
                var button:UIButton = self.view.viewWithTag(2) as UIButton
                button.hidden = false
            }
            sender.selected = false
        }else{
                sender.selected = true
                var selectedCard = self.cardDeck.drawRandomCard() as PlayingCard
                sender.setTitle(selectedCard.contents, forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        }

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated and happy to amend the question as needed.

I've debugged this a bit and the button reverts to the image that is the image in default state before hiding. I've removed highlighting (and anyways the image for the highlighted state is not that one) and it still has that flicker.

I'm thinking maybe there is a default animation when a button goes into hiding that must be overriden, but I'm not sure.

Comment: How did you get the XML representation?

Comment: Right click on the .storyboard file and open as Source Code.

Comment: If nothing else helps you could try this: set the alphaValue of the button to 0 (is that possible?) before hiding.